# Template meta programming inside template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, specialization

I'm trying to pre create template member functions in an array, and index into that array using run time determined values.  The array is an array of pointers to template functions within Manager that I will specialize. I would like to call one of these functions from the process::send function. For example.

```
template<typename MatchT>
class Manager
{ 
    public:

    template <int P>
    void do();

     template<int P, int ...Ps>
     struct table : table<P-1, P-1, Ps... >{};

     template<int... Ps>
     struct table <0, Ps...>
     {
          static constexpr void(*fns[])()={do<Ps>...};
     };
  };

   template <typename MatchT>
   template<int... Ps>
   constexpr void(*Manager<MatchT>::table<0,Ps...>::fns[sizeof...(Ps)])();


//process.h

 #include "Manager.H"

template<typename MatchT>
class Process
{
   public:

   void send(Manager<MatchT>& mgr  );

   private:

    typename Manager<MatchT>::template table<5> _processtable;
};

 //process.c

 template<typename MatchT>
 void Process<MatchT>::send(Manager<MatchT>& mgr)
 {
     ERROR here:
     mgr.*_processtable::fns[1]();

 }
```

Error is " _processtable is not a class, namespace , or enumeration".

Comment: Why do you say that `_processtable` is a `template` in `mgr.template _processtable`?

Comment: Also your `Manager` class simply has no `_processtable` member

Comment: I was able to get it compile writing the line in question as `this->_processtable.fns[1]();`. Whether this is what you need, I do not know.

Comment: I need it to call the function that's part of the Manager object. If I use "this->_processtable" it wouldn't be called for the mgr object passed into send would it?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you are trying to do, but anyway there is no `_processtable` member in your `Manager` class, so writing anything like `mgr._processtable` is wrong.

Comment: I want to use processtable as pointers to pre generated template functions in the manager class, then call the correct function on the manager object from the process::send

Comment: In what class do you want to store `_processtable`? Anyway, if you want to know why your particular code fails, then I think I answered the question. If you want to know how to achieve such function calling, then either heavily edit the question explaining in details what you want to achieve, either ask a new one.

Comment: I've edited. Sorry if it wasn't clear.  I can store process table in either class I suppose. I'm wondering why it doesn't work from the process class.

Comment: I also don't get what you want to achieve, but, similarly to what @Petr already wrote before, you need to change `mgr.*_processtable::fns[1]();` to `mgr.*_processtable.fns[1]();` [live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IgS3HQhIchPsfaEn)

Comment: @m.s.  Thank you that looks to be ok. Why is it ".fns" rather than "::fns" ?  fns is a static member of table.

Comment: but `_processtable` is not a class name, it is the name of a member variable

Comment: Ahh. I'm slow today. You are right. Thank you